# Using eclipselink JPA and alter persistence context name while deploying on weblogic

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

While using JPA eclipse link, i would need my application to be deployed per tenant on a weblogic server. But this would not allow me to deploy multiple times with same persistene context name. So is there a way we can specify the persistence context name at runtime/deployment time?

Comment: Deployment time isn't runtime, and conceivably the persistence units are going to need different resources that you'll also need to change.  Or are all these tenants on the same database tables/schema?   You might want to look into EclipseLink's multitenant solutions http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm

Comment: In my case, tenant schema can exist in the same database, or they can provide a new database altogether. This link shared deals with providing option where in data are maintained in single table or per tenant table within same schema and not on different schema.

Comment: Can you please help clarify? Also what happens is when i first deploy my app to WLS it gets deployed perfectly. Then when i edit the plan xml to provide a different context root and different datasource and then deploy it back again to WLS, it gets deployed properly but it refers to same database that was pointed by tenant1. This is because app depends on same persistent unit name and this is not changed.